# value not changed when calling return function in react

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

export default function Reducer() {
  var usersdata = "jjhjhj";

  var initstate = {
    users: [],
  };

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type == "fetchdata") {
      return { users: action.data };
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initstate);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.org/users")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({ type: "fetchdata", data: data });
      });
  }, []);

  const handledata = () => {
    usersdata = state.users.length
      ? state.users.map((user) => <h3>{user.firstname}</h3>)
      : "Nothing to Return";
    return usersdata;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => handledata()}>
        Fetch Data
      </button>
      {<br />}
      {usersdata}//no change
    </>
  );
}
```

I need to change `usersdate` when calling function `handledata`, when printing `usersdata` inside a function it's ok but outside function it's not. I create function that I call it when pressing button, the value changed inside the function but after calling function and try to print the value nothing changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should store the value in the component's state and use useState to manage it

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
export default function Reducer() {
var initstate = {
users: [],
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
if (action.type === "fetchdata") {
  return { users: action.data };
} else {
  return state;
}
};
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initstate);
const [usersdata, setUsersData] = useState(""); // Use state to store 
usersdata
useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
dispatch({ type: "fetchdata", data: data });
});
}, []);
const handledata = () => {
const newData = state.users.length
? state.users.map((user) => <h3 key={user.id}>{user.name}</h3>)
: "Nothing to Return";
setUsersData(newData); // Update usersdata in state
};

return (
<>
<button className="btn btn-success" onClick={handledata}>
Fetch Data
</button>
<br />
{usersdata} {/* Display usersdata from state */}
</>
 );
 }
```